# reading a file in a function

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

C++, i have a set of code, i need to get information from a txt file and read each character and count how many A's, B's, C's, etc, the file is entirley made of letters, im just having trouble having my void function read from the file and sort it, if anyone could help me out id greatly appreciate it

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void getData(ifstream& inPara, ofstream& outChara, 
char texT[], int numLet[]);

int main()
{
ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
char ch[26] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 
'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 
'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'};
int numofCharacters[26] = {0};

inFile.open("Lab7.txt");//opens input file

if (!inFile)//runs error if inFile could not be 
opened
{
cout << "Error unable to open Input File" << endl;
cout << "Program Terminated!" << endl;
return 1;
}

outFile.open("Output.txt");//opens Output File

if (!outFile)//runs error if Output File could not 
be opened
{
    cout << "Error unable to open Output File" << 
    endl;
    cout << "Program Terminated!" << endl;
    return 1;
}
while (!inFile.eof())//runs program untile end of 
file
{
    getData()
}

inFile.close();
outFile.close();

return 0;
}

void getData(ifstream& inPara, ofstream& outChara, 
char texT[], int numLet[])
{

for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    if (texT[i]) {
        numLet[i]++;
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
    cout << numLet[i] << " " << endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Always good to see advice given and then completely ignored. It affirms my understanding of humanity.

Comment: I advise you to start with simpler exercises, such as counting the characters in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your getData() function is being called without passing any parameters to it, while its definition has multiple parameters. That alone should give you a compilation error.

If the code needs to read the file character by character, then use getc function. It could look something like this (you still need to do a loop and all...):

```
FILE* inFile = fopen(filename.c_str(), "r");
myChar = getc(inFile);
```